# Javascript Letter Frequency Graph Using Google Charts API [Homework]

Tags: javascript, api, charts

I have this assignment to enter a sentence in the textarea and then output it as a HTML Frequency Chart and then output it using the Google Chart API.

I was able to output it as the HTML Frequency Chart but I am stuck on the Google Chart API part.

At the bottom in the `generateApiTable()` function, I know the value for the seperate columns is being retrieved by the `data.join()` part but if I remove that, then I don't get the letters being displayed on the bottom. The default value being put in is always 5.

I already tried taking the for loops from the `generateTable()` function and put them in the `generateApiTable()` function and then replaced `data.join()` with `myHeight` but that only displayed the letter 'A' on x-axis with value 25 (which is correct) but I need the entire alphabet.

So my question is how would I go about populating the Google Chart Api image with the frequency values previously gotten (for the HTML table).

```
var image = new Image();
var frequency = new Array(26);
var letters = new Array(26);

function html_chart()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    input = document.getElementById("user_input").value
    table.innerHTML = generateTable(input);
}

function api_table()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("api_table");
    table.innerHTML = generateApiTable();
}

function getCharacterCounts()
{
    letters = {}
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(letters[input[i]])

        if (letters[input[i]] >= 0)
            letters[input[i]] += 1
        else
            letters[input[i]] = 0
    }
    return letters
}

function generateTable(input) {
    var Pos = 0;
    var max = 0;
    var myHeight = 0;
    var newInput = input.toUpperCase();

    for (i = 65; i < 91; i++) 
    {
        frequency[Pos] = newInput.split(String.fromCharCode(i)).length - 1;
        Pos++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < frequency.length - 1; i++) 
    {
        if (frequency[i] > max) {
            max = frequency[i];
        }
    }

    table = input + '<table>';

    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<td>Letter Frequency 100px</td>";

    for (i = 0; i < frequency.length; i++) 
    {
        myHeight = (frequency[i] / max) * 100;
        myHeight = parseInt(myHeight, 10);

        table += '<td height = "100" width = "10"><img src = "orange.gif" alt = "25" height = "' + myHeight + '" width = "5"></td>';
    }
    table += "</tr>";

    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<td></td>";

    for (i = 65; i < 91; i++) 
    {
        table += "<td>" + String.fromCharCode(i) + "</td>";
    }

    table += "</tr>";
    table += "</table>";
    return table;
}

function generateApiTable()
{
    labels = []
    data = []

    for (i = 65; i < 91; i++)
    {
        data.push(5)
        labels.push(String.fromCharCode(i))
    }

    return '<img src = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chd=t:' + data.join() + '&chs=717x100&chl='+labels.join("|") + 'A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z&chxt=y" />'
}

function eraseText() 
{
    document.getElementById("user_input").value = "";
}
```

*EDIT*
Html Code

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<textarea name = "text" style = "width:400px; height:200px" id = "user_input">The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dogs</textarea><br>
<input type = "button" value = "HTML Chart" onclick ="html_chart()">
<input type = "button" value = "Reset Test Data" onclick= "eraseText()">
<input type = "button" value = "Image Chart" onclick = "api_table()">
</form>

<div id = "table">
</div>

<div id = "api_table">
</div>

<style>
td {
    vertical-align:bottom; 
    horizontal-align:left; 
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
</style>
</body>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "code.js"/>
</script>

</html>
```